# Different font size in footnote

Tags: titles, fontsize, text-decorations

I'm having a problem in my template for abstracts. I have some reasons to do my own commands instead of using only `amsart` class.

As you can see, when I use `\underline{}` to identify the speaker, the font used on `\footnote{}` (which is used to pass the Institution) is different. Compare numbers 1 and 2.

### With `\underline`

[image]

### Without `\underline`

[image]

### Here is the minimal code

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\thetitle}{}
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{%
 \renewcommand{\thetitle}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\MakeTitle}{%
 \thispagestyle{plain}%
 \begin{center}%
 {\textsc{\Large\thetitle}}\\[2ex]%
 {\large\theauthors}%
 \end{center}%
}

\newcommand{\theauthors}{}
\newcommand{\Authors}[2][]{%
 \renewcommand{\theauthors}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\Institute}[1]{\footnote{#1}}
\newcommand{\Email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\Title{Insert title here}

\Authors%
[Jakob Bernoulli \and Leonhard Euler]%
{Jakob Bernoulli%
\Institute{University One. \Email{email1@email.com}}%
\and%
\underline{Leonhard Euler}%
\Institute{University Two. \Email{email2@email.com}}%
}

\MakeTitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underlining? What's that? Please, don't do it.

The problem is that the contents of `\Authors` is massaged several times and `\underline` uses math mode, so the result is that the font for the superscript is set at the wrong time.

You are luckier if you load `soul`:

```
\usepackage{soul}
```

and use

```
\ul{Leonhard Euler}
```

Comment: Ow, thanks for the explanation. I didn't know about the math mode. It would be nice if some errors on missing dollars had appeared. Well, thanks so much. The `soul` package comes with a basic install? I'll send the file to people to prepare the abstract. But this is not a real problem since I'll do the final version of booklet.

Comment: @Sigur I can't say about "basic installs", since I always do full installs.